# Apache axis error cannot find services.xml

Tags: web-services, tomcat, wsdl, apache-axis

When I try to restart the apache tomcat server it throws the error.

org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The services.xml file cannot be found for the service: {0}

The wsdl generated is actually blank and only contains the description from the services.xml file which does indeed exist under META-INF.

I am using eclipse, tomcat 5.5 and axis 2

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

even the default service only contains the word "Service" when I try to access it through the web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the wsdl was actually ok. IE was showing it for some reason by firefox wasn't unless I did view source. I guess the xml was not closed properly.